# Standard Deviation

Tags: java, math, statistics, standard-deviation

Hi I have created a code to calculate the standard deviation of a set of numbers, here my code below:

```
public class standardDev {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    double median = n % 2 != 0 ? arr[n/2] : (arr[n/2] + arr[(n/2)-1])/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(arr[i] - median,2);
    }
    System.out.printf("%.1f", Math.sqrt(sum/n));
 }
}
```

However when the input is this:

> 10
>
> 64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060

I get a different result from the expected answer.
My output: `30475.6`
Expected output: `30466.9`

But if I tried the input below I get the correct answer:

> 5
>
> 10 40 30 50 20

My output: `14.1`

Expected output: `14.1`

Comment: Standard deviation is based on the mean, not the median.

Comment: That's also not even the correct way to find the median.

Comment: And the reason it works with your second input is that by chance, the mean ( (10+40+30+50+20) / 5 ) happens to be 30, which is also the median.

Comment: Hi all thank you for all the comment my mistake it should be the mean not the median. EDIT: Okay I have to edit the code.

Comment: It will solve the problem i have tried it!

Comment: Thank you all! got it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote your code to actually calculate the standard deviation, which is based on the mean:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class standardDev
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        double sum = 0.0;
        double mean = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            mean += arr[i];
        }
        mean /= n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(arr[i] - mean,2);
        }
        System.out.printf("%.1f", Math.sqrt(sum/n));
   }
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/qY1wkw

Comment: Edited it and it worked! I used median instead of mean.

Comment: Why are you doing `Arrays.sort(arr);`?  Finding the mean and standard deviation are O(n) operations.  Sorting is O(n·log(n)) and is not needed for either calculation.